# Refactoring Common Code with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a working section using ActiveAdmin in which I was considering refactoring so there is not as much duplication (:street, :street2, :city, :state, :zip_code), but not sure necessarily how to do it or if it would be recommended. Here is an example of what I have:

```
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :street
      row :street2
      row :city
      row :state
      row :zip_code
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Location' do
      f.input :street
      f.input :street2
      f.input :city
      f.input :state
      f.input :zip_code
    end
    f.actions
  end

  permit_params :email, :street, :street2, :city,
                :state, :zip_code
```

This code is working fine and this example is shorter than what I currently have in production. Any ideas on how I can combine my common parameters and not have so much repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have all that much repetition here as the `show` and `form` actions have separate responsibilities. I suppose you could define an array and populate these fields dynamically:

```
def address_params
  %i(email street street2 city state zip_code)
end

show do
   attributes_table do
      location_params.each do |params|
        row param
      end
   end
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Location' do
    location_params.each do |params|
      f.input param
    end
  end
end

permit_params location_params
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach however. It's more trouble than it's worth and you'll likely want to decouple which parameters you're displaying in `show` vs. those that you're allowing to be updated in your form. In my opinion, your code is fine as is.

Comment: I see what you mean about that and thank you for the answer!